# Power Shell CSV to AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Maybe someone can to help?
I have a script it take parameters from scv and put them to AD, script work without mistakes but I`m does not have results from some reasone.
Please help!

```
Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Scripts\test4.scv" | ForEach-Object -process {Write-Host $_ }
{Set-ADuser|]= -Identity $_.DisplayName -extensionattribute5 $_.extensionattribute5}
```

example scv

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-aduser?view=win10-ps#parameters), the `-Identity` parameter on `Set-ADUser` must be one of

- A distinguished name
- A GUID (objectGUID)
- A security identifier (objectSid)
- A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

This means that you cannot use the DisplayName property from the CSV for this parameter.

Try:

```
Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Scripts\test4.scv" | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.DisplayName)'" -Properties DisplayName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        Write-Host "Setting extensionattribute5 property for user $($_.DisplayName)"
        $user | Set-ADuser -Add @{extensionattribute5=$_.extensionattribute5}
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User $($_.DisplayName) could not be found"
    }
}
```

<sup>Instead of `-Add @{extensionattribute5=$_.extensionattribute5}`, you may rather want `-Replace @{extensionattribute5=$_.extensionattribute5}`. This isn't clear in the question</sup>

Comment: @RenatBoizov Thanks for the nice feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Import-CSV -Path "$home\desktop\Scripts\test4.scv" | ForEach {
  Write-Host $_ 
  Set-ADuser -Identity $_.DisplayName -Add @{extensionattribute5=$_.extensionattribute5}
}
```

Your code was broken. Bracing was incorrect. Also Extended attributes are added with a hash table using -Add parameter.